# How to fix NameError: name 'variablename' is not defined?

Tags: python, variables, tkinter, sqlite

So I'm getting the error **NameError: name 'chris' is not defined** and I suspect it has something to do with global and local variables however I have already declared 'chris' as a global variable in a function.

Heres the code:

```
def ChrisFood():
    global chris
    chris = 1
    FoodSelection()

def JoshFood():
    global josh
    josh = 1
    FoodSelection()

def SamFood():
    global sam
    sam = 1
    FoodSelection()

def DanielFood():
    global daniel
    daniel = 1
    FoodSelection()

def JimFood():
    global jim
    jim = 1
    FoodSelection()

def SeanFood():
    global sean
    sean = 1
    FoodSelection()

def FoodSelection():

    global FoodSelectionWindow
    FoodSelectionWindow = Tk()
    FoodSelectionWindow.configure(bg="black")
    DateAdded = datetime.date.today

    FoodSelectionPlaceHolder = Label(FoodSelectionWindow, text = "Food selection will be added in the third iteration")
    FoodSelectionPlaceHolder.grid(columnspan=10)

    if chris == 1:
        with db:
            cursor.execute(''' INSERT INTO 'Breakfast_History' (CaloriesTotal, DateAdded, PupilNames) VALUES (?,?,?)''',
                           ([TotalCalories, DateAdded, "Chris"]))
    elif josh == 1:
        with db:
            cursor.execute(''' INSERT INTO 'Breakfast_History' (CaloriesTotal, DateAdded, PupilNames) VALUES (?,?,?)''',
                       ([TotalCalories, DateAdded, "Josh"]))
    elif sam == 1:
        with db:
            cursor.execute(''' INSERT INTO 'Breakfast_History' (CaloriesTotal, DateAdded, PupilNames) VALUES (?,?,?)''',
                       ([TotalCalories, DateAdded, "Sam"]))
    elif daniel == 1:
        with db:
            cursor.execute(''' INSERT INTO 'Breakfast_History' (CaloriesTotal, DateAdded, PupilNames) VALUES (?,?,?)''',
                       ([TotalCalories, DateAdded, "Daniel"]))
    elif jim == 1:
        with db:
            cursor.execute(''' INSERT INTO 'Breakfast_History' (CaloriesTotal, DateAdded, PupilNames) VALUES (?,?,?)''',
                       ([TotalCalories, DateAdded, "Jim"]))

    elif sean == 1:
        with db:
            cursor.execute(''' INSERT INTO 'Breakfast_History' (CaloriesTotal, DateAdded, PupilNames) VALUES (?,?,?)''',
                       ([TotalCalories, DateAdded, "Sean"]))

    db.commit()
```

Any help would very much be appreciated,

Thanks.

Comment: `FoodSelection` doesn't have `chris`, `josh`, etc defined...

Comment: but they're already defined in the other functions and they're global variables so surely they should be defined throughout the code?

Comment: no that's not how variable scoping works. Also stop using `global`, if a function needs a variable from another function, pass it in as an argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Defining global variable for something doesn't define it for all the functions in your script. That's not how global works. Global changes the local variable to the global scope see:

```
x = 1

def foo():
    x = 2   #<--- is a local variable x

def bar():
    global x 
    x = 3   #<--- became the global x
    print('changing global x')

foo()
print(x) # 1
bar()    #changing global x
print(x) # 3
foo()
print(x) # 3
```

Change your person food selection to pass the person instead:

```
def ChrisFood():
    FoodSelection('chris')

def JoshFood():
    FoodSelection('josh')
```

and then in your `FoodSelection` make it accept an argument and `if` off it:

```
def FoodSelection(choice):
    #what you have in here skipping to if

    if choice == 'chris':
        #do chris things

    elif choice == 'josh':
        #do josh things
```

Don't rely on `global` if possible. There's always a better way to do things than use `global`